# how do I store values of for loop separately in new line in python?

Tags: python-3.x

What I want to do is trying to get different values of `p_y_given_x` for different `sigma2_n` separately in each line? When I use `append` it gives me result in one array. But I want separate results for each 0.2 for `p_y_given_x`.

Is there any hint for me?

```
for sigma2_n in np.arange(0.2,0.9):

p_y_given_x= np.exp(-(y_new-alphabet[t])**2/2/sigma2_N)
```

the result should be like this

> p_y_given_x1=
>
> p_y_given_x2=
>
> p_y_given_x3=

....

ummmmm.... actually maybe this helps `f(x)=x+2`, `f(1)=1+2`, `f(2)=2+2` and etc, I want to use a for loop and define x inside it and for each iteration use one values of x and insert it inside the function and calculate the f(x), but i would like to get values of f(x) separately and compare them, for example like this:

```
f(1)
f(2) 
f(3)(separately in different lines)
```

not like this in one `array[f(1),f(2),f(3)]` for the last case we can use `append()`

Comment: Not sure what you're after, do you want to store a list `np.exp()` into three separate values? or are these text/string references some how?

Comment: I want to  get  p_y_given_x for each value of sigma2_n, for example sigma2_n=0.2 i would like to get a value for p_y_given_x, and for sima2_n=0.3 i would like to get another value for p_y_given_x and continue this procedure until the last value of sigma2_n which is0.9 and i would like to have 10 different & separate values for p_y_given_x in output

Comment: It sounds like you want [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to create `p_y_given_x# = ` but I'm not sure what you're asking. But It would be a shame if I didn't suggest that you create a dictionary instead and store the values as such: `results['p_y_given_x1'] = ...`.

Comment: is like y=x^2 for different values of x i would like to have different values of y however  i would like to get these values of y separately, y1, y2, y3 in different lines and compare them

Comment: You're talking math and I don't understand the description of what you're after. It might be me not understanding or your description being vague. I can't help much further, sorry.

Comment: ummmmm.... actually maybe this helps f(x)=x+2, f(1)=1+2, f(2)=2+2 and etc, I want to use a for loop and define x inside it and for each iteration use one values of x and insert it inside the function and calculate the f(x), but i would like to get values of f(x) separately and compare them, for example like this,f(1),f(2), f(3)(separately in different lines) not like this in one array[f(1),f(2),f(3)] for the last case we can use append()